# An innocent man kills his family because there was no hope

Tags: identify-this-movie, horror

**Summary:** A whole town gets attacked by gigantic weird and violent creatures (spiders and insects).

**Genre:** Horror.

**Production date:** I'm not really sure, but not that old. Probably something in between 2004 and 2009.

**Scenes I remember:**

- A whole town gets haunted by giant insects, including spiders, weird scary creatures. They all hide in a supermarket, many die and many survive.
- A crazy woman was reading the Old Testament mentioned something about children sacrifice and she wanted to kill a young boy there.
- The young boy is supposed to be the son of a the protagonist (probably) who will later be protected by his father.

> After the father puts his family in the car, he gets completely hopeless, stuck in the middle of nowhere and surrounded by the **weird violent creatures who will torture and eat his family, he takes the gun and shoots his family**. A few seconds later, rescuers looking like the US Marines come to rescue the town. They are pictured evacuating  the area and spreading some poison to the insects.

And that's how it ended: very sad, and disturbing.

The moral was obviously, never ever give up.

Anyone can help identify this movie?

Comment: I thought the creatures were not supposed to be insects and spiders, but rather different specimens of the same (unidentified) species.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is definitely [the Mist](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0884328/): [best ending](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=irsMogywHR0) to a horror movie ever.

[image]

Tom Jane, who is fantastic in it, insisted the ending not be changed or he wouldn't complete the movie. He was a big supporter of it.

It differs dramatically from the original ending of the Stephen King novella, but King was so impressed with how Frank Darabont adapted it he went on record:

> It is the most shocking ending ever and there should be a law passed stating that anybody who reveals the last five minutes of this film should be hung from their neck until dead.

Comment: Most definitely right. I read the first bullet and knew it was *The Mist*. Yes, great and sad ending.

Comment: And yet the spoiler is in the question title...

Comment: I know, right? GeorgeChalhoub better watch his back...

Comment: The novella is really good too. Never saw the movie, but I still remember lots of Stephen King's story - and I read it 15+ years ago.

Comment: Tom Jane is seriously underrated.  Loved the ending, as well.